# Help find the derivative of $e^{2^x}$ using the definition of the derivative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Let $f(x) = e^{2^x}$, where $e$ is the exponential function.

So the $f'(x)$ is:

> $\begin{align}f'(x) &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2^{x+h}}-e^{2^x}}{h}\\
>                       &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2^{x}2^h}-e^{2^x}}{h}
> \end{align}$

I don't know how to finish from here.

I believe the next step is to remove the $h$ in the denominator which means I need to factor out the $h$ in the numerator but I am not sure how to do it as that $h$ is an exponent of an exponent.

I know I can use the chain rule to arrive at $e^{2^x}2^x\ln 2$ but I would like to try it this way for practice.

Comment: I believe you'd use L'Hospital's rule to evaluate the limit.

Comment: But if the OP is ok with using L'Hospital then why wouldn't they just as soon use the chain rule?

Comment: What if I didn't know the L'Hopital rule? Will I be stuck for good?

Comment: I believe at the beginning $e^{2^{x+h}}\neq e^{2^x}*e^{2^h}$

Comment: @ChenmingZhang thanks for pointing that out. I've tried again but am still stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the proof:

prerequisite:

$\begin{align}e=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\end{align}$  from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)

now let's begin:

$\begin{align}f'(x) &=& \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2^{x+h}}-e^{2^x}}{h}\\
&=& e^{2^x}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2^{x}(2^h-1)}-1}{h}\\
\end{align}$

now let $2^h-1=y$ then $y=\frac{\ln{(y+1)}}{\ln2}$, and we know when $h\to0$, then $y\to0$. then we have:

$\begin{align}f'(x) 
&=& e^{2^x}\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{(2^{x}y)}-1}{\frac{\ln(y+1)}{\ln2}}\\
&=& e^{2^x}\ln2\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{(2^{x}y)}-1}{\ln(y+1)}\\
\end{align}$

Now we expand $e$ by prerequisite:

$\begin{align}f'(x) 
&=&e^{2^x}\ln2\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}2^{x}y}-1}{\ln(y+1)}\\
\end{align}$

and further let $z=2^x\ln(y+1)$, or equivalently $y+1=e^{\frac{z}{2^x}}$, when $y\to0$,$z\to0$. we get:

$\begin{align}f'(x) 
&=&e^{2^x}\ln2\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(e^{\frac{z}{2^x}})^{2^{x}}-1}{\frac{z}{2^x}}\\
&=&e^{2^x}\ln2*2^x\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{z}-1}{z}\\
&=&e^{2^x}\ln2*2^x\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{((1+z)^{\frac{1}{z}})^{z}-1}{z}\\
&=&e^{2^x}\ln2*2^x
\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks. The part where $y= \frac{\ln (y+1)}{\ln 2}$, its not suppose to be $h= \frac{\ln (y+1)}{\ln 2}$?